# Automatically click an menu button in youtube comments page using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, youtube, click, comments

I'm trying to implement a chrome extension to retrieve comments from youtube, a problem is that I want to sort the comments by timeline,one way is to click the "Top Comments" menu and then click the "Newest First" button, I've tried many ways to simulate this operation using javascript(both in content script and chrome console) but failed. Could someone give me some hints? thanks.

Example: see comments of a youtube video [here](https://apis.google.com/u/0/wm/4/_/widget/render/comments?usegapi=1&first_party_property=YOUTUBE&href=http://www.youtube.com/all_comments?v=HQuODiMlUsc&owner_id=UeDyF4pLhihZsN0CQ3qXlA&query=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HQuODiMlUsc&stream_id=UCUeDyF4pLhihZsN0CQ3qXlA&substream_id=HQuODiMlUsc&view_type=FILTERED&width=590&page_size=100&youtube_video_acl=PUBLIC&viewer_id=UCTdQ45ea9bW6zJJohy8jIHg&hl=en_US&origin=http://www.youtube.com&search=?v=HQuODiMlUsc&hash=&gsrc=1p&jsh=m;/_/scs/abc-static/_/js/k=gapi.gapi.en.EKe3duBii-U.O/m=__features__/rt=j/d=1/rs=AItRSTPsWJ9FBpglI0Gt6JE37bJ2DTHSyw#_methods=onPlusOne,_ready,_close,_open,_resizeMe,_renderstart,oncircled,drefresh,erefresh,onthumbsup,ontimestampclicked,onfirsttimecommenter,onhidefirsttimecommenterpromo,onallcommentsclicked,onfirsttimeplusonepromo&id=I0_1385298221178&parent=http://www.youtube.com&pfname=&rpctoken=13846606).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the comments it's a bad idea to do it using the web interface, instead you should use the API which is less prone to changes.

Useful link:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference#Comments_Feeds

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_api_query_parameters#orderbysp

https://developers.google.com/youtube/articles/changes_to_comments

Comment: I see, that's what I've tried first, but there are a lot of limitations by using API, such as invoking fraquency and the maximum records that can be retrieved(seems 500 or 1000 per video).